# Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined i am getting an error in this code at first line

Tags: backbone.js

i am getting an error in this code at first line plz help me  **Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "foo/:bar": "paramtest",
      "*action": "func"
    },
    func: function(action) {
      alert(action);
    },
    paramtest: function(p) {
      alert(p);
    }
});
new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using an old version of Backbone, something pre-0.5.0. `Backbone.Router` used to be called `Backbone.Controller` but [it was renamed as part of 0.5.0](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> **0.5.0** — *July 1, 2011*
>
> [...] `Controller` was renamed to `Router`, for clarity.

The second Google hit for "backbone tutorial" points me [at this tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/) which uses 0.3.3. There seems to be a lot of people using 0.3.3 asking questions about Backbone lately so the Google results are probably the problem.

You should upgrade to the latest version (0.9.2) of Backbone, you can get it from the [Backbone website](http://backbonejs.org/). You should probably be using the latest version of Underscore (1.4.2) as well, you can get that at the [Underscore website](http://underscorejs.org/).

Answer (score 4):

In your HTML file make sure you declare your underscore js file before your backbone js file.

Comment: You are awesome! Searched way too long for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your Backbone object does not have the `Router` property on it. Are you overwriting it somewhere?